# Connecting Internet in Ubuntu using mobile as modem via blutooth or datacable

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-10.10

I am using ubuntu and trying to connect internet using mobile phone as modem via data cable.But I do'nt no what the step wise procedure for this.
I am using the command "sudo hcitool scan" for the list of devices which are connect to the laptop.This command shows the list of devices and MAC addresses.
Now for finding the which channel in my phone assign for what services,I am using the command "sudo sdptool browse 12:12:12:12:12(for ex.)".
Now what step I should follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try with Network Connections as this provides all the options for network connections. Try connecting with mobile broadband. The list for known service providers is already there.

System -> Preferences -> Network Connections -> Mobile Broadband  + ADD

Comment: Yes,It also work,But it is also a another way to connect from the net.